# jquery - event listeners: why does only one of the scripts work?

Tags: jquery

I am running rails 3.1 and have the following jquery script in a file /app/assets/javascripts/procedures.js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.unselected').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('unselected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $('.selected').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('unselected');
  });
});
```

The first action works as expected (selecting), but unselecting does not work.

On the other hand, this script works as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tile').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('unselected');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('unselected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('unselected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }   
  }); 
});
```

Is it because event listeners are only assigned when the script is first run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the class `.unselected` to an element after binding to that click handler wont affect the new elements with that class. you have to use jQuery `.on()` to bind to all `.unselected` elements, current and future. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Change your `.click()`s to be like this, for both `.selected` and `.unselected`:

```
$(document).on("click",".unselected",function(){
    // toggle your classes here
});
```

Comment: Also consider using this method for toggling classes: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: If there is some parent element (for your `.tile` elements) in your DOM that is available once the document is loaded, substitute its id-selector for `document` in the script above for improved efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Because Jquery Binds the event to element on `document.load()` and when you change the class to `unselected` then it does not mean that you have binded the event with that element.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click','.unselected',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('unselected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $('body').on('click','.selected',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('unselected');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Document.Ready executes as soon as the Document loads.

I am not sure, but this specific problem says that, yes, the functions in the document.ready are defined as soon as the DOM loads. Now, when the DOM loads, it finds div "unselected" only.  So, it binds the respective function to this class. On the other hand, it is unable to find div "selected", so it cannot bind bind function to this class.

I would request any expert to please justify this answer if its right. Otherwise tell what is right!.